# Как авторизоваться на сайте и спарсить значение python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Решил написать бота для игры bomb party на сайте [jklm.fun](https://jklm.fun), однако не могу спарсить сайт. Мне нужно получить буквы в центре. Если отправить запрос на url лобби (например на фото jklm.fun/TNVP), то попадаешь на страницу, где просит ввести логин. Подскажите, как это обойти. Спасибо.

Мой код:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://jklm.fun/MRWR"

req = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
syllable = soup.find_all("div", class_="syllable")
```

То, что выводит req.text:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>JKLM.FUN: Party games — PC &amp; Smartphone. BombParty, Master of the Grid, PopSauce &amp; co.</title>
  <meta name="description"
    content="Chill multiplayer minigames: trivia quiz, word, guessing, drawing games and more. Great for streams and hangouts!">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/common/fonts/fonts.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/common/base.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/room/room.css">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

  <meta property="og:title" content="JKLM.FUN: Party games — PC &amp; Smartphone">
  <meta property="og:description"
    content="Fun online browser games to play with friends or strangers. Free and easy. Great for streams and hangouts!">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://jklm.fun/images/icon512.png">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://jklm.fun/">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="url">JKLM.FUN/<span class="roomCode"></span> <span class="icon"></span></span>
      <span class="room"> <span class="playerCount">?</span> <span class="roomName"></span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="volume"><button class="toggleMute"></button> <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5"
        value="50"></div>
    <div class="mainBadge"></div>
    <button class="sidebarToggle" hidden>◀</button>
  </div>
  <div class="pages">
    <div class="loading page">
      <div data-text="loading">Loading…</div>
    </div>
    <div class="disconnected page" hidden>
      <div class="title" data-text="disconnected">Disconnected </div>
      <div class="reason"></div>
      <div><a href="" data-text="reload">Reload</a> <span data-text="or">or</span> <a href="/" data-text="goHome">Go
          home</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="setNickname page" hidden>
      <form class="setNickname box">
        <div data-text="enterYourNickname">Enter your nickname:</div>
        <div class="line">
          <input class="styled nickname" type="text" placeholder="Your name" data-placeholder-text="yourName" required
            minlength="2" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
          <button class="styled">OK</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="main page" hidden>
      <div class="game"></div>
      <div class="sidebar" hidden>
        <div class="tabs">
          <a href="#" class="chat active" title="Chat" data-title-text="chat">️</a>
          <a href="#" class="room" title="Room" data-title-text="room">‍‍‍</a>
          <a href="#" class="changeGame" title="Change game" data-title-text="changeGame" hidden>️</a>
          <a href="#" class="leaveRoom" title="Leave room" data-title-text="leaveRoom"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="chat pane">
          <div class="log darkScrollbar">
            <button class="setChatFilter" title="Filter chat..." data-title-text="setChatFilter"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="input"><textarea placeholder="Type here to chat" data-placeholder-text="typeHereToChat"
              maxlength="300"></textarea></div>
        </div>
        <div class="room pane" hidden>
          <div class="darkSettings">
            <fieldset disabled>
              <div class="setting privacy">
                <div class="label" data-text="roomPrivacy"> Room privacy</div>
                <div class="field">
                  <select>
                    <option value="public" data-text="roomPrivacy.public"> Public</option>
                    <option value="private" data-text="roomPrivacy.private"> Private</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div class="people">
            <div class="loading" data-text="loading">Loading…</div>
            <div class="content" hidden>
              <div class="filter">
                <input type="search" class="styled" placeholder="Search people…" data-placeholder-text="searchPeople">
              </div>
              <div class="list darkScrollbar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="userProfile pane" hidden>
          <div class="loading" data-text="loading">Loading…</div>
          <div class="content" hidden>
            <div class="picture"><img width="64" height="64"></div>
            <div class="nickname"></div>
            <div class="auth"></div>
            <div class="badges"></div>
            <div class="manage">
              <button class="styled toggleBan" data-text="ban">Ban</button>
              <button class="styled toggleMod" data-text="mod">Mod</button>
              <button class="styled toggleMute" data-text="mute">Mute</button>
            </div>
            <div class="ipAddress" hidden></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/common/dom.js"></script>
  <script src="/common/settings.js"></script>
  <script src="/common/getPostJson.js"></script>
  <script src="/common/text.js"></script>
  <script src="/room/room.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Область, которую нужно спарсить:

[image: скрин]

Comment: Открыть инспектор браузера и на вкладке Сети смотреть какие запросы идут, после повторить их в коде

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, как это реализовано [здесь](https://github.com/msesjrl/BombPartyBotJKLM/blob/main/main.py), мне кажется использовать selenium в вашем случае это будет лучший вариант

Answer (score 0):

Для авторизации на сайте нужно отправить `post` или `get` запрос на сайт.

1. Для начало нужно получить атрибут `name` тега `input`, отвечающего за логин.
   Например здесь - `<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="login" />` тег `name` имеет значение `login`.
2. Надо создать словарь данных, которые хотите отправить. В качестве ключей использовать значение атрибута(ов) `name`. В нашем примере это будет выглядеть так - `datas = {'login' : "логин, который вы хотите ввести"}`. Если помимо логина есть ещё например пароль, то просто добавляете и его - `datas = {'login' : "ваш логин", 'password' : "ваш пароль"}`.
3. Создаете сессию `s = requests.Session()` и отправляете данные на нужный URL  `s.post(URL, data = datas)`

Конечный код авторизации должен выглядеть так:

```
import requests

datas = {'login' : "ваш логин"}

s = requests.Session()                                          
s.post(URL, data = datas)
```